# Linq Get Collection of collocated equal objects

Tags: c#, linq, collections

The following code shows what I want to do:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> DoIt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> that)
{
    if (that == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (that.Count() > 1)
    {
        var result = new Collection<IEnumerable<T>>();
        var collection = new Collection<T>();

        collection.Add(that.ElementAt(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < that.Count(); ++i)
        {
            if (!that.ElementAt(i).Equals(that.ElementAt(i - 1)))
            {
                result.Add(collection);
                collection = new Collection<T>();
            }

            collection.Add(that.ElementAt(i));
        }

        result.Add(collection);
        return result;
    }

    return new Collection<IEnumerable<T>>() { that };
}
```

I'm only using custom implementations like that one, if there is no appropriate implementation already existing. Is there any way to do the same with the standard framework?

Comment: Why don't you also explain what your method is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I think he's grouping by items that are equal to one another AND next to one another (contiguous rather than collocated).

Comment: Avoid use ElementAt() and Count() They are very costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no traditional way to do this with the standard framework.  I do have a couple of issues with your solution though.

1. The use of `ElementAt(i)` is very inefficient and can cause the `that` collection to be iterated many, many times.  This can lead to performance issues
2. The use of `Count` also can be costly as it can cause a full enumeration of `that`
3. Unlike most LINQ methods it doesn't use deferred execution.  To fix this you will need to use a `yield return` style solution.

Here's an alternative solution

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> DoIt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> that) {
  using (var e = that.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (!e.MoveNext()) {
      yield break;
    }

    bool hasMore;
    do {
      var item = e.Current;
      var list = new List<T>();
      list.Add(item);

      hasMore = e.MoveNext();
      while (hasMore && item.Equals(e.Current)) {
        list.Add(e.Current);
        hasMore = e.MoveNext();
      }

      yield return list;
    } while (hasMore);
  }
}
```

Comment: `hasMore` should be declared outside of the `do` block so it can be referenced in its `while` clause, right?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the missing closing brace to your `using` block. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Frédéric not at all. Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use SequenceEqual which "Determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements by using the default equality comparer for their type" in case you are dealing with ordered collections http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Otherwise collection1.Intersect(collection2).Count()==collection1.Count

will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do in a chained statement. I am not sure if I would advise code like this though!

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> DoIt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> that) {        
    return that.Zip(that.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.Equals(b) ? 1 : 0)
        .Aggregate(
            (IEnumerable<int>)new []{1, 0}, 
            (c, x) => (new []{c.First() + 1}).Concat(c.Skip(x)), 
            _ => _.Zip(_.Skip(1), (to, skip) => new {skip, take = to - skip}))
        .Reverse()
        .Select(_ => that.Skip(_.skip).Take(_.take));
}
```

Comment: I've not tested it, but wouldn't the use of Zip with a part of itself lead to a nearly-full copy of the hole collection?

Answer (score -2):

Use the Any() extension method